# How to get all string variations where two adjacent letters are switched / swapped

Tags: python, string, list, nlp, autocorrect

What is the most elegant way to get all possible variations of a string where two adjacent letters are switched? For Example, if we have the string `'stack'` the desired result should be:

```
['tsack', 'satck', 'stcak', 'stakc']
```

My solution:

```
w = 'stack'
[w[:i-1] + w[i] + w[i-1] + w[i+1:] for i in range(1, len(w))]
```

Comment: `[w[:i] + w[i:i+2][::-1] + w[i+2:] for i in range(len(w)-1)]`. This solution uses 2 characters less. But readability is not as good as in your solution, IMHO.